# Modulo operator for generics java

Tags: java

I have one java class which computes modulo. Below is the code

```
public class HashMapV2<T extends String,V> {

    public void add(T key, V value){
        int modulus = Integer.parseInt(key) % size;
    }
}
```

The add function works fine for above i.e. If you check at class level I have `T extends String`. 
But if i changed it to like `T extends Integer` and changed the add method code to like

```
public class Modulo<T extends Integer,V> {

    public void add(T key, V value){
        int modulus = key % size;
    }
}
```

Then my code complains that:

> Operator '%' cannot be applied to 'T','int'

Why it is complaining? Is is not doing unboxing of Integer to its primitive type?

Comment: Where is `size` defined?

Comment: btw `Integer` is `final` (_cannot be extended_).

Comment: On another note, you can do `int modulus = key.intValue() % size;`...

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Can't reproduce on Java 8 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question :

> Why it is complaining? Is is not doing unboxing of Integer to its
>   primitive type?

Generics don't apply for primitives!

Answer (score 1):

- Without going too much into detail as is the type system simply
  cannot do it.
- `<T extends String,V>`  as well as `<T extends Integer,V>` doesnt make too much sense as both `String` and `Integer` are *final* classes (meaning they cannot be extended).

  You could actually make it work by doing `int modulus = key.intValue() % size;` but as mentioned above there is no point in making `T` generic as it can only ever be an `Integer`.

Thus, it would make sense to declare your class as follows:

```
class Modulo<V> {
    public void add(int key, V value){
        int modulus = key % size;
        ...
    }
}
```

for completeness, your other class should also just be:

```
class HashMapV2<V> {
    public void add(String key, V value){
        int modulus = Integer.parseInt(key) % size;
        ...
    }
}
```