# Operator '%' cannot be applied to 'T', 'int'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm creating a method to check wether a number is even or odd (just to understand generic types).
Here's my code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkEven(5));
    }

    static <T extends Number> boolean checkEven(T x){
        if(x % 2 == 0) return true; //int this line I get the message
        return false;
    }
}
```

Intellij says "Operator '%' cannot be applied to 'T', 'int'"
What's wrong?

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Does this [link for another person question at the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631081/modulo-operator-for-generics-java)answer your question?

Comment: The compiler cannot guarantee that `T` will be a class for which autoboxing will apply. For example, the compiler won't autounbox a `BigDecimal`, which is a subclass of `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can gain access to the numerical value of the instance of `Number` using [the methods that this class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue--) offers.

The method name checkEven implies that the parameter will be treated as an Integer, so you can use `intValue`. You can of course also check the `doubleValue` if that fits your needs more.

Of course this will only work for subclasses of `Number` that can be represented by an `int` or `double` respectively.

```
static <T extends Number> boolean checkEven(T x){
    int numValue = x.intValue();
    return numValue % 2 == 0;
}
```

You can also use intValue to implement that "square the number" method you mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you really can't do anything generic over all kinds of numbers -- even assuming that all kinds of numbers have a % operation.  (What would you do for a complex number?!)

You will need to pick a numeric type like `int` or `long` and use that.

Comment: `Number` offers the `intValue()` method, so this would be the way to go.

Comment: @f1sh: While that's possible, I don't think it's really satisfactory.  Suppose I have the `Double` 2.5.  Is that _even_?  Using `intValue()` would say yes, but I don't think it's a meaningful question to ask, which reflects -- again -- that `Number` isn't really the right type anyway.

Comment: then use `doubleValue` as it's more precise and it also works if the generic type is Integer. I am not saying this is good design, but there's definitely a way to get that numeric value out of that `Number`.

Comment: But how can I do if the number type isn't known?
I also created a method to square the number and I get the same message. I don't want to print 16.0 if the number is 4, instead, I want to print 16 (not 16.0).

Comment: @Rachid: You can't.  Make a method for every type you want to support.  (To be clear, trying to deal with numbers is the _worst_ way to learn about generics.  Numbers are a terrible example of how generics work in Java.)

Comment: It's true. I guess I will learn it by creating objects.